# Rails not saving all attributes to database Roo gem not reading values correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, rails-activerecord, roo

I am trying to retrieve some data from an `excel 2010` workbook and store into `sqlite3` database with `Rails` and `Roo gem`. The application is not saving all the attributes to the database as I want.

Here is my import method in the Beneficiary model

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  spreadsheet.each_with_pagename do |name, sheet|
    for i in 1..sheet.last_row do
      beneficiary = Beneficiary.new()
      beneficiary.name, beneficiary.gender, beneficiary.age, beneficiary.in_school, beneficiary.venue =
      sheet.excelx_value(i, 2), sheet.excelx_value(i, 3), sheet.excelx_value(i, 4), sheet.excelx_value(i, 5), sheet.excelx_value(1, 1)
      beneficiary.save!
    end
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then
      Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    when ".xls" then
      Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
    when ".xlsx" then
      Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else
      raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

And here is my database migration script:

```
class CreateBeneficiaries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :beneficiaries do |t|
      t.string :name #, null: false
      t.integer :age #, null: false
      t.string :gender #, null: false
      t.string :in_school #, null: false
      t.string :venue
      t.string :learning_center
      t.string :facilitator
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When I included the `not null` constraints, I got errors, but when i removed them, some attributes where not saved. Hence I think the problem is with my `import` method, but I don't know why.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show errors you are getting?

Comment: @PardeepDhingra it give an error like this when i uncomment the not null constraints, SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: beneficiaries.in_school: INSERT INTO "beneficiaries" ("name", "gender", "age", "venue", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). But when i remove the constraints, it does not save all the attributes.

Comment: I guess it's because of `age` column. Its integer but `roo` default will return it as `string` which is marking it `null`. Try after removing `false` validation from `age` col.